# Symfony2 Assetic Dynamic Image Inclusion in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, assetic

I want to load a specific thumbnail for an article using Twig and Assetic.  Here is the code that doesn't work:

in config and params:

```
thumbnail_dir="/Resources/public/images/article_thumbs"

twig:
    debug:             %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
    globals:
        thumbnail_dir: %thumbnail_dir%
```

In the twig file:

```
{% image '@MyMainBundle' ~ thumbnail_dir ~ '/' ~ id ~ '/' ~ article.thumbnailFile %}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}"
         alt="{{ article.title }}" />
{% endimage %}
```

So basically I have images I'm storing in /Resources/public/images/article_thumbs/{ID}/{FILE.ext}

I want to get those for a specific article in Twig. How can I achieve that?

**EDIT:**
Why am I not putting them in the web folder?

I guess I had thought about using Assetic filters at some point, but I suppose there is really no need.

I'll just store them in the web folder for now.

So if I make `thumbnail_dir="/images/article_thumbs"` and put that in the web dir, Do I just say `{{ asset( thumbnail_dir ~ '/' ~ id ~ '/' ~ article.thumbnailFile ) }}` in twig?

Comment: Why you storing them in Resources not in web folder?

Comment: Images should be in the resources folder

Comment: Then using `app/console assetic:dump` you move them to the `web`folder. Each time you add an asset to the `Resources/public` folder you have to run the above command. If you are editing `css` or other files that you need to see immediately, you can use `app/console assetic:watch` that will refresh automatically the files on each modification. See the documentation for more details: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#dumping-asset-files-in-the-dev-environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Kriswallsmith this is not possible using assetic.

https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/60

If I understood correctly:
Since assetic does not render the Twig the variable is not being read.